# WSO2ESB using XMPP protocol

Tags: wso2, xmpp, wso2-esb

Has anybody managed to get XMPP protocol working successfully with WSO2ESB ([WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus](https://wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus/))?

I have managed to get the server setup correctly and it registered on [Openfire](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/) as a session. From there nothing seems to work. I have deployed a service which has xmpp as a transport. The service deploys successfully but it doesn't seem to create a session on Openfire and the xmpp endpoint url appears not well formed:

```
xmpp://wso2esb@null/services/XMPPPOC
```

As you can see the domain is coming out as null.

I  can find no issues in the wso2esb log or the openfire logs to indicate any problem.

Has anybody has any success using XMPP as a protocol with WSO2 products (at all, let alone ESB). It seems to be that it doesn't work and it certainly appears scantly documented.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.